# How can I reference a class in MVC project that retrieves data from database with asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have *MVC* application which contains a class called *DataAccess* that retrieves data form a database. I added *asp.Net* Core application and I referenced the *MVC* application in the *asp.Net Core* application.
The problem is that when I call one of the DataAccess methods and compile the solution, I get an error:

> Error CS0012  The type 'DataTable' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

See below code for my .net Core API:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using shopping;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;

    namespace ShoppingAPI.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class ValuesController : Controller
        {
            // GET api/values
            [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult  Get()
            {
                DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
                da.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM USERS;", new List<DbParameter>());
                return Ok();
            }
}
```

Can anyone advise me?

Comment: Could you check your reference?, I think you won't see system.data  under it. if so add it as a reference

Comment: you must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data... (Add reference > Assemblies > Framework).

Comment: Yeah so your library is compiled against .NET Framework, not .NET Standard? Or you don't have a reference to System.Data.

Comment: Are you trying to reference MVC 4/5 from AspNetCore? As CodeCaster mentioned, you won't be able to do that because MVC 4/5 is on .NET Framework and AspNetCore is on .NET Core (unless your AspNetCore app targets .NET Framework). You are better off putting shared functionality into its own .NET Standard class library so it can be referenced from both UI frameworks and on both platforms.

Comment: Im trying to reference MVC 4. I tried to call a method from another class in the referenced MVC project which does not use databases and it works which means that the error occurs only with classes that retrieves data from databases.
I checked the referenced project and System.Data is there. In the .net Core app, I added System.Data.Common

Comment: Your ASP.NET Core was created using the full .NET library or the .NET core one?

Comment: Its targeting .net Core

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, then right-click on your project and select `Edit *.csproj` and let us know what it says inside `<TargetFramework>` -- it should be `net462` or similar (just NOT `netcoreapp`) -- you need to target the .NET Framework for your solution to work.

Comment: <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>

Comment: I just want to say that I have a method that returns a string inside my DataAccess() class and when I call that method it works fine. The problem occurs only when I call a method that deals with databases. Should I add the same connection string in my .Net Core as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Solution

**Step 1. Target the correct framework**

With the assumption that you are using Visual Studio 2017 here is how you can solve your problem.

1. Right-click on your project and select `Edit *****.csproj`
2. In the `.csproj` file, you need to replace the target framework to the .NET Framework.

for example:

> ```
> // incorrect
> <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
>
> // correct
> <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
> ```

[image: frameworks]
source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

For a list of the **Target Framework Moniker (TFM)** (ie, `net47`, `netstandard2.0`, `netcoreapp2.0`, etc.*) you can check this link out: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

**Step 2. Run dotnet restore**

> Go to your output window and run `dotnet restore`.

Sometimes Visual Studio may misbehave (depending on which update you have installed), so you may have to close and re-open your Visual Studio. Otherwise, sometimes a clean/re-build may do the trick.

### Wnat Are We Doing?

According to your comments, you noted that you were trying to reference a project that was MVC4, which means it was likely not written using a library that is supported directly with the .NET Core framework. Instead, it would be supported by the .NET Framework (w/ .NET Core) instead.

The solution above just does that for you.

Comment: I changed TargetFramework to net462 but now I cat access any class from the referenced project. Any idea?

Comment: I already did what in step 2. I repeated the same steps again and added `System.Data.Common` to the .Net Core API and it works now. 
Thank you guys!